# I am not able to change my DE to DE that I just installed?

Tags: linux, fedora, desktop-environment

Hi I just fresh installed Fedora but I wanted to try mutiple DEs like :`cinnamon, KDE or MATE` so I run commands to install them which did pretty well. But when I reboot and try to `change my DE in login screen` **it only gave me 2 options for DEs** `Gnome and i3`. How can I change my DE to `Cinnamon , KDE or MATE`? Thank you for all your answers and advices.

Comment: If you write about a login screen, I presume that some Desktop Manager is responsible for launching your DE. You probably need to change it first or, at least adapt its configuration. Which DM are you using ?

Comment: @MC68020 Hello I am using `Gnome DM` but I am not satisfied with it it was there by default. And yes I was talking about login screen.

Answer (score 0):

When one wishes to use a [login (or Display) Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager), it will be responsible for launching the Desktop Environment.

Most DM are configurable and should be capable to launch any DE with more or less graceful transitions depending on the graphic framework used (qt / gtk)

Most commonly used are :

- GDM : Recommended for the Gnome DE (and from then its cinnamon and mate forks)
- SDDM : Recommended for KDE Plasma 5 and LXQt
- [LightDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM) : Lightweight and highly configurable since it is compatible with both GTK and Qt.

If you decide to switch to LightDM (what I reco since you want to switch between Qt based DEs and GTK based DEs) then after installing the package together with its GTK and KDE greeters, you 'll probably need to disable the automatic launch of gdm at boot if it is set and then enable LightDM using `systemctl enable lightdm`

Default configuration should fit to start with, if you need more then you'll need to dig into /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/*.conf files having the knowledge of [all tunables](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/main/data/lightdm.conf).